# AngularJS Custom Validation Directive with http post

Tags: angularjs, validation

I'm trying to validate a form input field generated by ng-repeat which is using a custom directive to handle the validation, as it requires quite specific formatting.

I've got the whole flow mostly working, but I can't get the final step to display the error message for each field. Here are some snippets from the code...

**Part of the template:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="vehicle.form" ng-submit="submitForm(vehicle.form.$valid)" novalidate>

  <div class="vehicles_row" ng-repeat="vehicle in rows" ng-class-odd="'row_odd'" ng-class-even="'row_even'">
    <div class="vehicles_table_cell">
      <ng-form name="vrmFieldForm">
        <label>Vehicle Registration</label>
        <input type="text" name="vrm" ng-model="vehicle.vrm" required dr-vrm-format />

        <div class="control-group messages" ng-messages="vrmFieldForm.vrm.$error" ng-if="submitted">
          <span ng-message="required">Required field</span>
          <span ng-message="format">Invalid format</span>
        </div>
      </ng-form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addRow()">Add Row</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="btn_disabled">Save all Vehicles</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

**The Custom Directive:**

```
angular.module('vehiclesApp').directive('drVrmFormat', function($http) {

  // Matches function to loop through array until VRM pattern is found
  var matches = function(registration, patterns) {

    var vrm = registration.toUpperCase().replace(/\s+/g, ''),
          i = patterns.length,
    pattern = false;

    while(i--) {
      if(vrm.match(patterns[i])) {
        pattern = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    return pattern;
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.format = function(modelValue) {
        $http.post('/Fleet/ValidateVrm.php', modelValue)
        .then(function(response) {
          if(matches(modelValue, response.data)) {
            console.log('Valid');
            return true;
          }
          console.log('Invalid');
          return false;
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

The http post service calls a script which queries a database and returns a JSON encoded array of regex patterns based on the data being sent in the modelValue. Each input value is then run through the 'matches' function to see if the format entered matched one of the possible patterns.

I know this is working as I can see the valid/invalid output in the console for as many rows created by the ng-repeat. However when I try to return the response to the UI, the error messages are not displaying, even when there is an error.

**One more thing...**

I took this from another example which tests for odd/even input values and this Does work.

```
angular.module('vehiclesApp').directive('drVrmFormat', function($http) {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.format = function(modelValue) {
        return modelValue % 2 === 1;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

It's able to identify whether each input in the repeating form has an error and display a message next to each one accordingly. So I know I'm very close with this, I just need a way to communicate the true/false bool to the UI (I think). Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of returning a bool, can't you just set the validity of the field? `ctrl.$setValidity(field, bool)`

Comment: Hi Matheno, I tried that and it comes up with an error, 'a.replace is not a function'. I tried `ctrl.$setValidity(elem[0], true);` in the if condition but I can't seem to identify each row in this case (by setting [0]) it's still not working.

Comment: Hi Matheno, I've got this working thanks to you, woohoo. You were right, using the $setValidity was required, and also a bit of tweeking of the naming conventions. In the end I used `ctrl.$setValidity('vrmformat', true);` and changed the name of the directive, and the ng-message all to 'vrmformat'. Bingo.